# Groovy ternary operator prints null

Tags: java, groovy, null, ternary-operator

I am attempting to eliminate a large amount of IF/ELSE statements from my code with the use of the ternary operator.

```
 //Checks to see if person exists      //if not then add       //else print

 println doesPersonExist(personName) ? addPerson(personName) : 'No such person'
```

The problem is that if the addPerson(personName) method is executed then NULL is printed due to the println. Is there anyway of NULL from printng to the console? I understand i could remove the println but then 'No such person' would not print.

UPDATE: I finally managed to get this working as required - i simply removed the println and also 'No such person' and replaced them with this:

```
 doesCarrierExist(carrierName) ? exists() : addCarrier(carrierName)
```

Where the exists method simply called a println statement within the base class. I hope this helps anyone that has a similar problem in the future.

Comment: The correct way to avoid printing `null` is to avoid calling `println`. In other words, you should change your code back to using `if` statements. There is nothing wrong with them.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `doesPersonExist(personName) ? addPerson(personName) :println( 'No such person'`)`?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you mix 2 different actions.

1. The print method.
2. The addPerson(personName).
   And you wish to print that into the screen.

The best way is handling it as 2 separate handles one for each action (for the addition and for the printing).

If the addPerson(personName) returns a String result you can print to the console the result by using the following Groovy code section:

```
def textResult = doesPersonExist(personName) ? addPerson(personName) : ""
println(textResult)
```

Note: If you are using Java language replace the 'def' with 'String'.